# Almost sure equal

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Does there exist any continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $P(X\neq Y)$ is neither equal to 0 nor 1?

Edit:

My approach to the problem was similar to the one by Peter Foreman, but less straightforward. I studied
\begin{align}
P(X\neq Y) &=P(X<Y \text{ or } X>Y) \\
&= P(X<Y)+ P(X>Y) \\
&= P(X-Y<0) + P(X-Y>0) 
\end{align}
My idea was to calculate these terms on examples where X an Y are independent, because I can then use that: if the X and Y have a joint PDF, then the PDF of X-Y is a convolution of the PDFs of X and Y. My experimentation made me conjecture that $P(X\neq Y)$ assumes either the value 0 or 1, when X and Y are continuous random variables.

Comment: Assuming that $X-Y$ is also a continuous variable we can just write$$\mathbb{P}(X\ne Y)=\mathbb{P}(X-Y\ne0)=1$$

Comment: Have you made any attempts to answer the question?

Comment: @PeterForeman What if, e.g., $X = Y$ with probability 1? (Relatedly: the "assuming that $X - Y$ is also a continuous variable" part is doing quite a bit of heavy lifting here!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X, Z$ be two iid continuous random variable and let $B\sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ independently. Now let $Y = XB+Z(1-B).$ Then $Y$ is also continuous and $P(X\neq Y)= 1/2.$

Comment: Thank you. Is the assumption that X and Z are identically distributed always needed? I tried simulating your example and I find: if X is normal and Z is uniform, then the estimated CDF of Y appears to be continuous. Could you direct me on how two show that Y is also continuous?

Comment: X and Z might have different distributions, that is indeed fine. Y is called a mixture. You could look up mixture distributions, to see how to calculate its pdf (it's the average of the pdf of X and Z).